# Programatically adding a remembered username/password to IE?

Tags: internet-explorer

If I wanted IE to remember a username and password combo for a specific site (not in a text form, but an [authenticated login](http://newwebmasters.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/authenticate.gif)), how could I programatically add that to IE's database of stored usernames and passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think this is possible due to security reasons. If adding to the DB is possible then even reading may be possible which is scary ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if your program runs in the same user account as IE than you can do everything IE can.

[This article](http://www.nirsoft.net/articles/ie7_passwords.html) describes where IE saves all the different types of passwords - with links to utilities that can read them.

I have written code that reads IE's auto-complete saved password (that are stored using a completely different mechanism than the ones you want) and it wasn't difficult.